# Can Word documents from Mac be opened in Windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, pages

I received MacBook Air for Christmas. I am a university student, and use Word for essay writing. It seems that this MacBook has 'Pages'. I post my essays online through a specific way, as they calculate if my work is acceptable etc. I don't know if my lecturers will be able to open the essay documents, especially if I've typed it from this laptop.

Is there any way I can make sure they will be able to access my work? Do I need to buy specific office sources, or will this be ok to use?

Comment: Word documents written in [Word for Mac](https://products.office.com/en-US/mac/microsoft-office-for-mac?omkt=en-US) usually are compatible. You probably asking for Pages documents **exported/saved** to/as MS Word document format...

Comment: You can use Microsoft Office for Mac. You can use Pages to write and export to MS Word format.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that you are a student, you can download Microsoft Office for Mac for free from the [Microsoft website](https://products.office.com/en-us/student/office-in-education) (only your university email address will be necessary).

This will provide access to your work from your new MacBook Air.

Answer (score 1):

Pages can export to Word format, but it does not make sense to use this app when the people grading your work are using Word for Windows, because you cannot predict what sorts of incompatibility problems will arise.  By all means get Word for Mac and use that instead.